# Alert message if there is new data on server

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, alert

I'm building a simple PhoneGap application where I get new messages from MYSQL server and show them to the user. The application is supposed to  get a JSON like this

```
 {
    "key": [
        {
            "Message": "test"
        }
    ]
}
```

from server every minute and alerts if there is something new. But right now it alerts message "test" every time even though the JSON has changed to this:

```
{"key":[]}
```

after the application has asked it from the server the first time.

This is the JS I use

```
 setInterval ( "getMessages()", 60000 );
function getMessages() {
    $.getJSON(serviceURL + 'messages.php' ,function(result){
    $.each(result.key, function(index, field){
    alert(field.message);
  });
});
}
```

Comment: Could it be because `field` is undefined so it uses the previous one?

Comment: is your always json containing an array of one element ? Or could you have more than one key/object inside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request is probably being cached by your browser.  Change your url to:

```
serviceURL + 'messages.php?' + new Date().getTime()
```

this will trick the browser into thinking it's a different request each time and therefore avoids issues with caching.